# Example PHPUnit Test on Laravel 5.4 fails with 404

Tags: php, testing, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.4

I can my project on Laravel 5.4 from link: localhost:8888/streaming_statistic/public

I have a test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ApiTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

I run all tests with command

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

But result is:

```
PHPUnit 5.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 222 ms, Memory: 12.25MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\ApiTest::testBasicTest
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/streaming_statistic/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:56
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/streaming_statistic/tests/Feature/ApiTest.php:16

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

I can open this page http://localhost:8888/streaming_statistic/public/
I have an route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

What i am doing wrong?
And what the right way to write tests for controller methods in laravel? May be the HTTP tests it not the best solution for them?

Comment: You need to setup the right URL and Port for your tests.

Comment: Where can i configure them?

Comment: APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8888/streaming_statistic/public - for tests this env variable was wrong... I changed root directory to streaming_statistic/public and env to APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8888 - and got OK (1 test, 1 assertion)!

Comment: You can edit that on phpunit.xml file to affect just testing environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

for tests this env variable was wrong...

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8888/streaming_statistic/public
```

I changed root web server directory to streaming_statistic/public and env to

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

After that i got:

```
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: You might want to validate if the test is actually passing. It might be that on 127.0.0.1:8888 it's seeing a list of all directories and not really reaching your application.

Answer (score 0):

I have Locked the same error on 5 hours, Finally, I got a solution,

Change the `APP_URL=http://localhost` in

> .env.testing

file

Check the below link about `.env.testing` file

[.env.testing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/testing)