# error 404 on example test with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.4

Using Laravel 5.4, I can't run the example test provided for phpunit:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Running command `phpunit` from the root of my project outputs:

```
PHPUnit 6.0.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F.                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 147 ms, Memory: 12.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::testBasicTest
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/home/username/public_html/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:76
/home/username/public_html/myproject/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php:21
```

With my `.env` at root contains:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/~username/myproject/public
```

I saw [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189472/example-phpunit-test-on-laravel-5-4-fails-with-404), but the answer was useless.

Any idea?

**Edit:**

Note that the url `http://localhost/~username/myproject/public/` is perfectly working through a browser.

Comment: Does your site work OK through a browser?

Comment: @NigelRen yes, stable version of the site is working. Current dev version returns error 500 for every page, except the root url which is working through a browser. That's why I wanted to run test, but this example which is a request to the root url is not working in the first place

Comment: Can you add `echo env('APP_URL', '?');` to your test to verify it has the right config.

Comment: @NigelRen `echo env('APP_URL', '?');` returned `http://localhost/~username/myproject/public`, so it is the right config, isn't it ?

Comment: add virtual host, and use that domain for APP_URL

Comment: Do you have a route defined for / ?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan that solved the problem. Would you make it an answer ?

Comment: @wasthishelpful np )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add virtual host, and use that domain for `APP_URL`.

In Ubuntu 17.04, you can do so by creating a `.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/laravel/project/public"
    ServerName name.of.your.virtual.host

    <Directory "/path/to/your/laravel/project/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then enable the virtual host with the apache command:

```
sudo a2ensite name.of.your.file.conf
```

And finally restart apache:

```
systemctl reload apache2
```